# IIS Hosted website in not running on another machine. Try my best but not able to find issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, localhost

I have an asp.net MVC project which I publish and then create a website in IIS local machine. So now it's running well on my machine but it's not running on another machine. I try a lot but don't know why it's happening?

1. on default web site I have added port 80 in bindings and running that IP to another machine.
2. Also, I have created Inbound Rules in Firewall setting for port 80. by referring https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/access-website-hosted-on-iis/

But still, it's working on local machine but not working on another machine. It's showing on the page like "This site can't be reached" and "unexpectedly closed the connection" and "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED".

So how to go out of this issue?

Comment: Can you run a very simple static html webserver and reach that one? If that works, try the simplest example you can find and work your way up there. Is the .net-version in your application pool correct?

Comment: @ChristopherThonfeld-Guckes I have check other local hosted website. It's working fine in local machine as well as remote machine.

Comment: Make sure your application pool (IIS-Management -> Application Pools -> _your_app_pool_) has the right .net version. 2.0 is default on some older versions. 4.0 is the version you want for any .net-Framework 4.x.x projects.

Comment: there is default 4.0 version on apppool but still it's issue is there. Other all website is running very well.

Comment: I had a similar issue back, I selected all options in IIS setup in Programme and Features option on windows, and restarted the machine, it started working

Comment: @satsvelke In my case all IIS featured are already selected.

Comment: is your both machine are on the same lane?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal yes both machine are on same lane. Other website is running on another machine but only single website which I want to run on other machine that is causing problem for access website from another machine.

Comment: So only particular one website causing issue in IIS that mean you need to check web.config file. Also for reference you can compare that part with another hosted website's config file.

Comment: @HardikDhankecha. I have check there is rewrite content is mention there in web config file and in global asax file https is also define there. So can it affect to publish on IIS ?

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments for run your website in local environment. try by putting those content in comment and try with turn of firewall. Possibly firewall can cause issue for accessing your publish url from another machine.